# Securevalue in Azure ARM template for App service similar to ACI secure values

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-container-instances

I have a Nodejs app running in Azure App service. Currently it is obtaining secrets through the azure api

example:

```
    const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

    // Build the URL to reach your key vault
    const vaultName = `${process.env.VAULTNAME}`;
    const url = `https://${vaultName}.vault.azure.net`;
    
    // Lastly, create our secrets client and connect to the service
    const client = new SecretClient(url, credential);
```

As the app service is deployed through an ARM template where the keyvault and secrets are generated I was wondering if there is a better method such as using secure values like for container groups or loading them into the environment.
I also generate a container instance where I use my generated secrets:

```
"environmentVariables": [
                                {
                                    "name": "example",
                                    "secureValue": "[parameters('generated_secret')]"
                                }
                        ],
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results***

*I have the the container app to store the secrets as a new environment variables*

*I have used this [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/manage-secrets?tabs=arm-template#defining-secrets) for custom deployment template*

*We have to change the parameters for environment_id, location and Queue-connection-string in  parameters section*

```
{ 
"$schema":  "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/deploymentParameters.json#",  
"contentVersion":  "1.0.0.0",
"parameters":  {
"location":  {
"value":  "XXXXX" 
},   
"environment_id":  { 
"value":  "XXXX"
},
"queue-connection-string":  {  
"value":  "XXXXXX"
}
} 
}
```

*If we don't add the parameters it won't display here and while deploying we will get the error*

[image]

Please make sure if we give the environment_id then only it will deploy

*Click on* ***review and create*** *the deployment will be created and the secrets will be stored as environment variables for container app.*

*After deployment if we click on container app we can see the secrets got created*

[image]